# LWC - Send email popup

Tags: lightning-web-components

When clicking on a contact's email address in the compact layout and the standard contact page a little popup for filling out an email appears. Is there a way to replicate this behavior in LWC? I've tried mailto links but that hasn't worked.

[image: Contact page email link]